# Integral equation solution in power series

Tags: integral-equations

Given the integral equation

$$ g(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x-y)f(y) \, dy$$

for a known function $ g(x) $ and kernel $ K(x)$.

Of course I know this is a Wieener-Hopf integral equation but I would like to know another formula, if possible in power series to solve this equation. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to put $ dy $.

Comment: Did you consider the Fourier transform?

Comment: i know how to solve it with the foruier tranfsorm of course i was asking if there is another method to solve this integral equation for example by power series